# Angularjs get id cross html files

Tags: angularjs, google-places

I have divided the whole page(post.html) into two pages. The right one shows google map(with search box) and the left one I use  to make the post_side.html page showing up.

Inside the post_side.html, I use  to make some other pages shows up by nested states.

The problem is that I cannot get the input id(the search box in post_side.html or even some other files) to control the map(shows in post.html) without trigger(no button click).

If it is possible to make this happen?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Comment: Thanks @Qaddura it's helps!